# Give only one output for each test value

Tags: python, sorting

This is a program for picking the string with number(s) in them. It gives output repeatedly if there is more than 1 number in each input.

For example, I have "test123" as input and the program will give me 3 of them as output since there are 3 numbers in it.

I'm only a python self learn beginner so please help me out, thanks for your time and have a good day!

```
num_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
f = open("testfile.tsv", "r")
content = f.read()
content_list = content.splitlines()
f.close()

def split(stuff): 
    return [char for char in stuff]

for a in content_list:
    words = split(a)
    for b in words:
        if b in num_list:
            print(a)
```

FYI:
"testfile.tsv":

```
test
test123
testing
123
123456
```

Comment: What is the part of your code the causes the output to occur? Does it make sense for it to happen at that point in the code? What is the rule that tells you when to output something?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel At the last few line, *for b in words: if b in num_list: print(a)* Since the program is checking each word by character, it will give x amount of same output if there are x amount of numbers in it

Comment: Okay. Do you understand why it gives that amount of output, based on the loop structure? Can you think of a place where you can put the output statement, that will cause it to only run at most once? Now, can you think of a way to *remember* whether or not something was found, so that it can only print the one time when appropriate?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks for the reply! I understand why it is doing this but still can't figure out how should I fix it. Could you please be more specific on what should I fix/add? It will really help me out a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a character/string is a number, just use isnumeric().

i.e.

```
def split(stuff): 
    return [char for char in stuff]


f = open("testfile.tsv", "r")
content = f.read()
content_list = content.splitlines()
f.close()

for a in content_list:
    words = split(a)
    num_count = 0
    for b in words:
        if b.isnumeric():
            num_count += 1
    print("%s has %d numbers" % (a, num_count))
```